# Как заставить регулярку остановиться, достигнув определённой подстроки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Имеется кусок HTML-файла, состоящий из повторяющихся блоков переменного содержимого, вроде такого:

```
<a>...<b>1111111</b>...."222222222".....<in>3333333</in>....</a><a>...<b>1111111</b>....<in>3333333</in>....</a><a>...<b>1111111</b>...."222222222"....</a><a>...<b>1111111</b>....</a>
```

RegEx: `<a>.*?<b>([^<]*)(?:[^"]*"([^"]*))?(?:.*?in>([^<]*))?.*?a>`

`11..`, `22..`, `33..` - это данные, которые необходимо из него вытащить, а `...` - это любые ненужные данные, которые в том числе могут содержать и другие тэги. Первый блок всегда присутствует, а остальные опциональные.
Проблема в том, что если я делаю опциональные группы `(?:.*?in>([^<]*))?` , по при отсутствии элемента `<in>...</in>` эта группа захватывает этот элемент из следующего блока, т.к. `.*?` пропускает всё до него. Добавление `<\/a>` в конец запроса не помогает.

Вопрос: как заставить RegEx останавливаться по достижении конца блока (`</a>`) если между элементами могут быть любые символы, кроме, собственно, границ элементов и тэга конца блока?..

PS: RegEx - pcre, HTML файл условный для наглядности, [тестировал тут](https://regex101.com/r/gA0iG0/1).

Comment: я, честно говоря, ничего не понял, но посмотрите вот тут, может, чем-то поможет - https://regex101.com/r/dM0bV1/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Включаем все необязательные группы в одно ИЛИ так, что бы были захвачены либо они либо любой символ, [вот так](https://regex101.com/r/gA0iG0/2):

```
<a>.*?<b>([^<]*)(?:"(.*?)"|<in>(.*?)<|.)*?a>
```

Правда есть побочный эффект, блок в кавычках может встречаться после блока `<in>` и если блоков в кавычках несколько - будет захвачен последний. Обойти думаю можно, но очень муторно. Так что если во входных данных таких ситуаций нет по определению, то сильнее заморачиваться и не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо, очень похоже на то что мне нужно.